# XML schema not found even if specified in file

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm trying something as simple as generating XML that respects the rules of an XML Schema. However, I have not myself specified the XSD file and have just been given an example of how the header of my XML should be, but for some reason the schema can not be found automatically by e.g. **Notepad++** or by `XmlReaderSettings` in my C# project.

Here is a example of my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PBSXML000:FullDelivery xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://pbs-erhverv.dk/online/xml/bs/pbsxml000bigmax http://pbs-erhverv.dk/online/xml/bs/pbsxml000bigmax.xsd" xmlns:PBSXML000="http://pbs-erhverv.dk/online/xml/bs/pbsxml000bigmax">
  <PBSXML000:DeliveryStart>
    <PBSXML000:DataSupplierCVR>00000</PBSXML000:DataSupplierCVR>
    <PBSXML000:DataSupplierSysCode>000</PBSXML000:DataSupplierSysCode>
    <PBSXML000:DeliveryId>12345678</PBSXML000:DeliveryId>
    <PBSXML000:DeliveryCreateDate>211119</PBSXML000:DeliveryCreateDate>
  </PBSXML000:DeliveryStart>
  <PBSXML000:SectionStart>
    <PBSXML000:CreditorPBSNr>12345678</PBSXML000:CreditorPBSNr>
    <PBSXML000:SectionNr>0112</PBSXML000:SectionNr>
    <PBSXML000:DebtorGroupNr>1</PBSXML000:DebtorGroupNr>
  </PBSXML000:SectionStart>
  <PBSXML000:DebtorIdentification>
    <PBSXML000:DebtorCustomerNr>99100045</PBSXML000:DebtorCustomerNr>
    <PBSXML000:AgreementNr>999100012</PBSXML000:AgreementNr>
    <PBSXML000:DuePayDate>01122019</PBSXML000:DuePayDate>
    <PBSXML000:DebtorCVROrCPRNr>12345678</PBSXML000:DebtorCVROrCPRNr>
  </PBSXML000:DebtorIdentification>
  <PBSXML000:M601Record>
    <PBSXML000:RecordType022>
      <PBSXML000:DebtorNameAddr1>Hans Ole, blalba 17, st th</PBSXML000:DebtorNameAddr1>
      <PBSXML000:DebtorPostCode>2100</PBSXML000:DebtorPostCode>
      <PBSXML000:DebtorCountryCode>DK</PBSXML000:DebtorCountryCode>
    </PBSXML000:RecordType022>
    <PBSXML000:RecordType042>
      <PBSXML000:SignCode>1</PBSXML000:SignCode>
      <PBSXML000:Amount>100095</PBSXML000:Amount>
    </PBSXML000:RecordType042>
    <PBSXML000:RecordType052>
      <PBSXML000:TextNoteRecordNr>11335</PBSXML000:TextNoteRecordNr>
      <PBSXML000:TextLine>Ost - den gode</PBSXML000:TextLine>
    </PBSXML000:RecordType052>
  </PBSXML000:M601Record>
  <PBSXML000:DebtorIdentification>
    <PBSXML000:DebtorCustomerNr>12345</PBSXML000:DebtorCustomerNr>
    <PBSXML000:AgreementNr>12345</PBSXML000:AgreementNr>
    <PBSXML000:DuePayDate>01122019</PBSXML000:DuePayDate>
    <PBSXML000:DebtorCVROrCPRNr>12345678</PBSXML000:DebtorCVROrCPRNr>
  </PBSXML000:DebtorIdentification>
  <PBSXML000:SectionEnd>
    <PBSXML000:Amountin601>1334690</PBSXML000:Amountin601>
  </PBSXML000:SectionEnd>
  <PBSXML000:DeliveryEnd>
    <PBSXML000:NrOfAll042in601>54</PBSXML000:NrOfAll042in601>
    <PBSXML000:TotalAmountin601>0</PBSXML000:TotalAmountin601>
    <PBSXML000:NrOfAll052in601>32</PBSXML000:NrOfAll052in601>
    <PBSXML000:NrOfAll022in601>22</PBSXML000:NrOfAll022in601>
  </PBSXML000:DeliveryEnd>
</PBSXML000:FullDelivery>
```

And the header of the schema file is this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:PBSXML000="http://pbs-erhverv.dk/online/xml/bs/pbsxml000bigmax" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://pbs-erhverv.dk/online/xml/bs/pbsxml000bigmax" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
```

When I try to test is just get the error:

Failed to locate the main schema resource at

> 'http://pbs-erhverv.dk/online/xml/bs/pbsxml000bigmax.xsd'

Do you have any idea why this simple thing fails?

Comment: Works for me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found a workaround, I could just specific add the schema from the url to the xsd, it's not perfect but I can live with it :)
If someone has a similar problem I just used:

```
XmlReaderSettings readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        readerSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        readerSettings.Schemas.Add("http://pbserhverv.dk/online/xml/bs/pbsxml000bigmax",
            "http://pbs-erhverv.dk/online/xml/bs/pbsxml000bigmax.xsd");
```

As to just make it fetch the xsd.

Answer (score 1):

Your XML correctly specifies an associated XSD via `xsi:schemaLocation`.  I am able to validate it and determine:

1. **Warning**: Large `maxOccurs` values are being interpreted as `unbounded`.
2. **Error**: `PBSXML000:DataSupplierCVR` has to have 8 digits.

If you are getting errors regarding failure to locate the specified XSD, try loading that XSD via a web browser to check connectivity.

Comment: How did you test it?? I have not found a single tool which worked!
Optimal I would like to be able to do it in C# :)

Comment: Oxygen XML Editor